# How can I import module from project

Tags: python

How can I add a import task module to my execute module?
This is a

```
aaa/
    bbb/
        ccc/
           tasks.py
    ddd/
        eee/
           execute.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the directory of `tasks.py` to the path and then import:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("../../bbb/ccc/"))
import tasks
```